# Como faço para definir apenas um font-size na font de forma que ela vai diminuindo de acordo com o tamanho do dispositivo?

Tags: css3, layout-responsivo, css-font-size

Duvida rápida pessoal, como faço para definir apenas um `font-size` na font de forma que ela vai diminuindo de acordo com o tamanho do dispositivo?

Atualmente estou inserindo um tamanho de font-size diferente para cada `@media query`, existe uma forma mais inteligente de se fazer isto de forma que defino uma unica vez e ela vai se ajustando de acordo com o `article` ou `div` em que ela esta?

Comment: Eu acho que se você usar `em` como medida, não é necessário fazer isso. Da uma lida [nesse post sobre unidades de medidas](http://tableless.com.br/unidade-pixels-em-rem/)

Answer (score 3):

Ao invés de utilizar `px` no tamanho, informe `em`, sendo que o valor `1em` é a fonte no tamanho normal e `2em` o dobro do tamanho. Tente achar um valor que te agrada (Ex.: `1.5em`, `1.2em`, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o novo font-size relativo

```
1.5vw = 15px font size
```

ex: `font-size: 1.5vw`

porem ainda só existe suporte para

IE10,
IE9,
Chrome 22+,
Safari 6 e iOS Safari 6,
Firefox 19 (late February 2013),
Blackberry Browser 10